# Ember.js: access the current component from helper

Tags: ember.js, components, helper

Looking for any solution (even dirty hacks) to access the current component from a custom helper.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.extend({
  compute() {
    ... who is computing me? ...
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It seems you most likely want to implement behavior of a component in a helper. You may want to check out how Ember Components can accept positional parameters (like the inline version of the `link-to` helper does for example)

Comment: I want to write a custom helper that generates classes for tags.

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass `this` to the helper.

Say the code example you mentioned is for `format-currency` helper, so you can pass the context like `{{format-currency value this}}`

And in the helper you can access it like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.extend({
  compute([value, container]) {
    //... who is computing me? ...
    // container is computing you
  }
});
```

Comment: This is what I resorted for and I hate repeating this part over and over :( Hoped that I'm missing something simple and obviouse, but no. May be digging deeper into `{{outlet}}`, `{{yield}}` or some other built in feature would help, however those are quite complex.

Comment: This is the valid answer, but it is not a good pattern for Ember.